# Vue.js component stops working after returning error from server

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have big component which works like x-editable plugin: when user cliks on field it becomes editable, when user clicks outside - field becomes simple text and request with new data is sent to server for validation and storing of new value.

When server returns code 200 (validation has passed) - everything is ok.
When server returns code 403 with error text inside body of response - any subsequent clicks do not trigger update event;

Here is excerpt from my vue.js component (function which is called whenever input is changed)

```
onInputChange() {
            switch(this.inputType) {
                case "select":
                    this.value = this.input.select2("val");
                    break;
                case "date":
                    let d = this.input.datepicker("getDate");
                    if(d) {
                        this.value = moment(d).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                    }
                    break;
                case "phone":
                    this.value = this.input.val();
                    break;
                case "password":
                    this.value = this.input.val();
                    break;
            }
            if(this.postUrl) {
                let self = this;
                self.errorText = "";
                self.isProcessing = true;
                this.$http.post(this.postUrl, {
                    name: this.name,
                    pk: this.pk,
                    value: this.value
                }).then((response) => {
                    // saved
                    self.isProcessing = false;
                    if(self.isEnabled) {
                        switch(self.inputType) {
                            case "date":
                                self.input.datepicker("hide");
                                break;
                        }
                        self.isEnabled = false;
                    }
                    if(self.model && self.pk) {
                        window.VueBus.$emit(self.model + "_" + self.pk);
                    }
                }, (response) => {
                    self.errorText = response.body;
                    self.isProcessing = false;
                })
            }

        },
```

This is an error, which I see in console

> app-vue.js:1860 POST http://localhost:8000/user/edit 403 (Forbidden)

In network tab I see that request returned correct error message: "Input too short"

Comment: any errors from console?

Comment: `DD/MM/YYYY` is not a useful date format. Whenever you transmit dates between technical systems, please use `YYYY-MM-DD` without exceptions. You can always format the dates for display, but for transfer or storage in files you *really* should use the standardized format.

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` is desirable indeed, but a timestamp is a good alternative.

Comment: Well it's not proabably directly vue issue - you have some restrictions and backend, so API return 403 status code.So consider about making your code to send correct data to the server.

Comment: It is not about backend. Vue.js component receives data when server returns 403 and sets errorText inside component. The problem is: it stops updating after it.

Comment: have you tried commenting out pieces of the error handler to see if there is an issue with the variable? I can only guess that there might be an issue with setting `self.errorText = response.body`. Are you outputting `errorText` somewhere where the format might cause issue? like a `{{ errorText }}` or a `v-html="errorText"`?

Comment: @JustinMacArthur yes, it is the problem, but what is returned from server as simple as "Input is too short". No tags, no line breaks.

Comment: Unless response.body is undefined. at which point you'd be relying on an undefined value where vue might stop working.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this diff resolved the problem

```
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
                    'form-group': true,
                    'floating-label-form-group': true,
                    'col-lg-12': true,
-                   'has-error': errorText,
+                   'has-error': errorText.length,
                    'floating-label-form-group-with-value': value.length > 0,
                    'floating-label-form-group-editing': isEnabled
            }"
 @@ -110,7 +110,7 @@

                    </span>

-           <p class="help-block" v-if="errorText">
+           <p class="help-block" v-show="errorText.length">
                    {{ errorText }}
            </p>
```

I replaced `errorText` with `errorText.length` in template. In all cases errorText is just a string (without html formatting).